# Python game mechanics: restarting program

Tags: python, while-loop

Newbie here. What I'm trying to make is a text- based game with multiple levels. Each level has a few choices that determine whether a player moves on to the next level or not.
Here's the main problem: if a player loses a level, no matter what level, the program has to restart from the beginning.

Here's the general format of the game:

```
restart = True
while restart:
    print "Level 1"
    x = input("Question:...>ans1< >ans2< >ans3<")  #assume ans1 is always correct
    if x != ans1:
        print "GAME OVER"
    else:
        print "Continue"
        restart = False
    restart = True
    print "Level 2"
    x = input("Question:...>ans1< >ans2< >ans3<") 
    if x != ans1:
        print "GAME OVER"
    else:
        print "Continue"
        restart = False  #etc.
```

Restarting the game depends on whether the variable "restart" is true or not, but switching back and forth every level does not seem like a feasible or efficient way to do this. If anyone has any advice/ ideas/ better solutions please respond as soon as possible.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order for the value of your variable `restart` to have an impact on whether the block of code under the while loop is executed, the expression after while (here, restart) needs to be evaluated. As your code is currently written, if the user succeeds at level 1, restart is changed to `False` and then back to `True`, without impacting the execution of the code block. If the user fails at level 1, restart remains `True`, and the code block goes on executing just the same.  In order for the while expression to be evaluated again (and the value of restart to have any impact on the execution of the code block, you either need to exhaust the code block, or to have a branch include `continue`, at which point execution of the code block stops and the while expression is evaluated.

Take a look here for some basic information about while loops:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would use a structure like a stack to control the current level and a dictionary to store the questions, answers, and level progression. Currently your game loop doesn't operate as a loop, but rather a logic chain, which is causing problems.

For example, this is what I wrote up:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from enum import Enum

class Commands( Enum ):
   Traverse = "go to"
   Restart = "restart"
   QuitGame = "quit"
   Backtrack = "backtrack"

def main( **kwargs ):
   debug = kwargs.get( "debug", False )

   # Answer option value:
   # Value 0: operation
   # Value 1: parameter

   # Operations:
   # "go to": traverse to level <parameter>
   # "restart": restart the game
   # "quit": quit the game
   # "backtrack": backtrack <parameter> levels

   beginning_level = 0
   level_options = { beginning_level: ( "question 0", { "go to 1": ( Commands.Traverse, 1 ), "go to 2": ( Commands.Traverse, 2 ), "restart": ( Commands.Restart, 0 ), "quit": ( Commands.QuitGame, 0 ), } ), 
                 1: ( "question 1", { "go to 2": ( Commands.Traverse, 2 ), "back 1": ( Commands.Backtrack, 1 ), "restart": ( Commands.Restart, 0 ), "quit": ( Commands.QuitGame, 0 ), } ), 
                 2: ( "question 2", { "back 1": ( Commands.Backtrack, 1 ), "restart": ( Commands.Restart, 0 ), "quit": ( Commands.QuitGame, 0 ), } ),
               } # clearly more could go here.

   try:
      level_stack = []
      quit = False

      while not quit:
         if not level_stack:
            level_stack.append( beginning_level )

         current_level = level_stack[ -1 ]
         level_question, options = level_options[ current_level ]

         print( "Level {:d}:".format( current_level ) )
         answer = input( "{}: {}> ".format( level_question, ", ".join( sorted( options ) ) ) )

         answer = answer.strip() # Be forgiving of leading and trailing whitespace.
         if answer in options:
            command, parameter = options[ answer ]

            if command == Commands.Traverse:
               level_stack.append( parameter )
               action_message = "Traversing to level {:d}.".format( parameter )
            elif command == Commands.Backtrack:
               for i in range( parameter ):
                  if level_stack:
                     level_stack.pop()
                  else:
                     break

               action_message = "Back-tracking {:d} step(s).".format( parameter )
            elif command == Commands.Restart:
               level_stack = []
               action_message = "Restarting game."
            elif command == Commands.QuitGame:
               quit = True
               action_message = "Quitting game."
            else:
               raise Exception( "Unsupported command: {}".format( command ) )

            if debug:
               print( action_message )
         else:
            print( "Invalid response: please try again." )
   except Exception as e:
      result = 1
      print( "Error {}".format( str( e ) ) )
   else:
      result = 0

   return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   sys.exit( main() )
```

`level_options` stores the game progression options and `level_stack` stores the path which has been taken thus far.